# How can I change the path/file name of index.html in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, react-scripts

When building a React (with usual `react-scripts`/`create-creact-app` etc.) app via `npm build`, I always get the entry file in `build/index.html`.

I've tried moving the `src` into a subfolder, but the `index.js` is required to be there in `src/index.js`.

So **how can I change the output path of the `index.html`?**

I.e. e.g. I want to rename it to `index.htm`, because I am have a pedantic quirk, or I want to change the output path to `build/srv/www/index.html`?

(These are just examples.)

Comment: You could move your entire `build` directory to `build/src/www` after the build?

Comment: @Tholle Obviously, it should work inside of the build process/while building.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the output path you need to change the webpack config, and in create-react-path is not possible unless you run the eject script.

This way:

```
npm run eject
```

After running it, you will be able to access to any project configuration (webpack config in your case), but you must know, once the project is ejected, you can't go back.

More information here:

[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md)